# Magento Enabled Compilation not Displaying Qty '+' or '-' on product page

Tags: magento, compilation

Magento Enabled Compilation not Displaying Qty '+' or '-' on product page when compilation is Disabled product Qty '+' or '-' is displaying. can any one suggest me to solve the issue.

Comment: You are using which magento version?

Comment: Magento Version 1.9.1.0.

Comment: That means you add custom code for Qty "+" and "-" right? because magento not gives this kind of feature.

Comment: Disabled Compilation is working Qty "+" and "-"

Comment: In which file you added your custom code?

Comment: i am using a template in that i have this option.

Comment: Its really very hard for me to resolve your issue like this. I need some basic information to resolve your issue. There are so many code available for add this kind of feature which are also work fine with or without compilation.